# AngularJS why returning a bool from a function is not the same as a property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I usually return true/false from a function and pass that function into a property, but in this case it is not working.

For example:

Passing false into isEnabled works:

```
 $scope.myDropDownConfig = {
        allowMultiple: false,
        onSelecting: $scope.onSelect,
        isEnabled: false;
    };
```

This does not work:

```
 $scope.myDropDownConfig = {
        allowMultiple: false,
        onSelecting: $scope.onSelect,
        isEnabled: function () {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Is the expression not being evaluated in time? I thought it would be the same as using a bool directly... no errors, debugger wont catch. Any ideas? Do I have to tell angular to evaluate an expression?

Comment: When do you want the function to be evaluated? Immediately, or at some other time?

Comment: I assumed that as soon as the isEnabled property is READ it is evaluated. Not the case... I need to initiate the expression evaluation from another function for this to work... I am just not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First property is simple property and the second property is a **function**. So you need to invoke the second with parenthesis `()`

1. `$scope.myDropDownConfig.isEnabled`
2. `$scope.myDropDownConfig.isEnabled()`

Comment: That's still not going to work if they are passing this object to Angular. They would need to do `$scope.myDropDownConfig.isEnabled = $scope.myDropDownConfig.isEnabled()`.

Comment: OP has not posted where it is being used, but a function is valid anywhere a javascript expression is required.

Comment: I don't follow. A function may be syntactically valid, but that doesn't mean the API is expecting a function. Simply invoking the function doesn't change the value stored in the object.

Comment: I understand now I need to fire off evaluation of that property, it will then be parsed by the object consuming it. I guess that is a limitation of the consumer, not angular or javascript. But I feel like this is a common enough pattern.